# apache superset dashbaord not rendeing

Tags: apache-superset

I have installed superset through docker and lauching the server in local host. But when I click the chart I don't see the dashboard - as it is not rendering.

There is no error message. Any help on this?

[image: click on Misc Charts]
[image: Dashboard view]

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and fixed it by rerunning the setup manually in my container. Hope this helps!

```
# Need to run `npm run build` when enter contains for first time
cd superset/assets && npm run build && cd ../../

# Start superset worker for SQL Lab
superset worker &
```

Link: https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/blob/master/contrib/docker/docker-init.sh

Comment: https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md is a great resource for getting started with building superset and setting up.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, and figured out that superset server gets web assets from superset/static/assets, which somehow didn't exist, so I created a link to superset/assets, like this:

```
$ls -la superset/static
lrwxrwxrwx  1 vagrant vagrant   24 Oct 30 03:39 assets -> /home/ss/superset/assets
```